# Cannot activate parameter cors.config

Tags: 8, configuration

I am using the **RESTful Web Services** that is included in core of Drupal 8.2.7.
I need to activate CORS to be able to call the API from another domain.

I put this configuration in this file: "core/lib/Drupal/Core/core.services.yml" but it didn't work. I don't have the header *Access-Control-Allow-Origin*.

```
cors.config:
  enabled: true
  allowedHeaders: ['*']
  allowedMethods: ['*']
  allowedOrigins: ['*']
  exposedHeaders: true
  maxAge: true
  supportsCredentials: true
```

I found also this configuration is present in "sites/default/default.services.yml".

What is the proper way to configure CORS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To override container variables you have to enable this line in `sites/default/settings.php` (is enabled by default)

```
$settings['container_yamls'][] = __DIR__ . '/services.yml';
```

and then copy `sites/default/default.services.yml` to `sites/default/services.yml`.

Now you can configure the variables in `services.yml`.